# What are UK rules on written material that is sexually explicit?

Tags: copyright, criminal-law, online, pornography

D is an adult who writes sexually explicit fan fiction which D posts to Tumblr and *Archive Of Our Own*. D always marks such writing as 18+ only and warns minors not to read or interact.

The fan fiction material does not contain any sexually explicit images, it is text only. The characters are all consensual adults, but often written as Character x Reader, in second person, i.e., Character x You. Otherwise described as self-insert fan fiction.

What is the UK law on sexually explicit material that is written and clearly marketed to adults online? What steps can an author take to avoid criminal liability for such posts?

Comment: Is this fanfiction text-only, or does it involve images? Does it involve minors as participants in sexual activities?

Comment: As edited I do not think this should be closed as a request for specific legal advice.

Comment: Pornography is not illegal in the UK, what would you be liable for? There are rules for fan fiction concerning copyright, both in terms of whether you violate the original and whether you can get copyright yourself but none of these depend on the fact that the fan fiction is adult only.